# Получение размера элемента при помощи JavaScript

Tags: html, javascript, css

Есть элемент:
`<img src="wallpapers/bg.jpg">` 
Как узнать размеры этого элемента или картинки, при помощи нативного `JavaScript` без использования `jQuery`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[xxx].height
document.getElementById('asd').height
```